# SOAP Client programming in Java

Tags: java, xml, http, soap, request

I have a really interesting problem with my Java application. I am trying to create a SOAP client but I do not want to use the built in or any other external libraries to make things work. I want to learn how it really works and set up all request and header information.

The program is working. I can send a request and get the response. However, when the response is bigger I get some 'junk' in the xml response which creates a new line and strings appear for example: b50, 51b, 5a8, 9ed or 15b. And these strings break the xml structure randomly in the response.

My code is:

```
package soapclient.client;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
/**
 *
 * @author stom7
 */
public class Client {

    private BufferedReader _reader;
    private DataOutputStream _writer;
    private Socket _socket;

    public void connect() {

        try 
        {
            _socket = new Socket("**.***.***.***", 80);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Connected successfully!");

        try
        {
            _reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_socket.getInputStream()));
            _writer = new DataOutputStream(_socket.getOutputStream()); 
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Streams created successfully!");

        String content = "The soap request in xml format";

        String request = "POST the_path HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                + "Host: the_host\r\n"
                + "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8\r\n"
                + "Content-Length: " + content.length() + "\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + content;
        try {
            _writer.writeBytes(request);
            _writer.flush();

            String line;

            while ((line = _reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        try
        {
            _reader.close();
            _writer.close();
            _socket.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }    
    }  
}
```

Even in the first line there is a problem:

```
51b
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Or:

```
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1
b50
" name="in6" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add a sample of a problematic XML (just a snippet of the part that breaks the XML)?

Comment: ?Why? are you intent on avoiding all the suitable libraries for the job?

Comment: I have just edited the question so you can the the respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the response is in chunked format which means those lines are hexadecimal numbers giving the length of the chunked parts. So the first line gives the length of the first chunk then a new line comes with another hex number and so on.